# pipe find to `file` (command) linux command recursive

Tags: linux, bash, file, recursion

I have a file system that looks something like this with unknown file types.

```
└── 63206
    └── 4443606
        ├── 6433
        ├── 712861
        ├── 726355
        └── 723714
```

For each file, I can do `file <filename>` and get a spec about it's dimensions.

`6433: PNG image data, 138 x 209, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced`

Can someone tell me how I might pipe this recursively so I could get an output like this for each file path in bash?

I tried something like `find | file`. I'm not supper familiar with piping bash.

Comment: find . | xargs file
this will print all files (and items in folders) in the current directory and passes it to file

Comment: FYI, `gm identify` (from GraphicsMagic -- also see the `identify` command from ImageMagick) is probably a better tool for this than `file`; it actually lets you specify a format string so you can get the exact metadata you want in whatever format is easier for you to parse.

Comment: Re: "piping", btw -- a pipeline connects one program's stdout to another program's stdin. If you can't tell `file` to read the name of the files to run against from its stdin, then you can't pipe a list of such files into `file` (without an intermediate tool such as `xargs` -- and that actually invokes its own bugs/complexities). Pipes thus aren't unconditionally the Right Tool for all kinds of connections between processes.

Comment: Even if a process *can* read its input from stdin (which `file` can), there's only one stdin stream -- if you want to run it against multiple inputs, this can mean needing to run one instance per input. Which is to say: `find . -type f -exec file -- {} +` is much more efficient than `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for arg; do cat -- "$arg" | file -; done'`, which is an alternative that sets up a proper pipeline and thus does what you're asking for in an entirely literal way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may want to add other conditions, but basically from top directory

```
find -type f -exec file {} \;
```

or

```
find path_to_dir -type f -exec file {} \;
```

Comment: I'd consider `-exec file -- {} +`; that way we're not invoking `file` more times than necessary, and can handle the case where the filename (with path) starts with a dash.